# Is it possible to save the text of the command line automatically?

Tags: rendering, command-line

When a rendering is made via command line, the progress is appreciated as follows:

```
Fra:1 Mem:16.90M (0.00M, Peak 17.44M) | Time:00:00.02 | Scene, Part 1-135
Fra:1 Mem:16.81M (0.00M, Peak 17.44M) | Time:00:00.02 | Scene, Part 2-135
Fra:1 Mem:16.90M (0.00M, Peak 17.44M) | Time:00:00.03 | Scene, Part 3-135
Fra:1 Mem:16.88M (0.00M, Peak 17.44M) | Time:00:00.03 | Scene, Part 4-135
Fra:1 Mem:17.11M (0.00M, Peak 17.44M) | Time:00:00.04 | Scene, Part 6-135
```

How can I automatically pass the text that is displayed when I perform the rendering to a text file on my hard drive?

Comment: Wich OS are you using ? For Linux: blender -b file.blend > file.txt

Comment: You are a genius! Yes, it's Linux and your answer works perfectly. Thank you!

Comment: @thibsert You should post that as an answer below.

Comment: I wasn't sure OP was using Linux, and I thought the windows syntax was different - surprisingly, it is not. Added as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tested on Linux and Windows, should work on MacOs too :

```
 blender -b file.blend > file.txt
```